# SQL Invalid Identifier when using bind variable

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, inner-join

Using my anonymous block I have written below, the bind variable is giving me the error: I've pasted a picture of the table below.

- edit: ETHI1022 is the input I'm giving for the CORID

```
v_corid CHAR(8) := ETHI1022;
                       *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-06550: line 3, column 24:
PLS-00201: identifier 'ETHI1022' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 0, column 0:
PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
```

I realize my inner join is most likely messed up like no other. I'm trying to learn this stuff and am having a very hard time learning how taking values from the select statement and placing them into the variables in the declare section works.

```
DECLARE
    v_marstuid MARKS.STUID%TYPE;
    v_corid CHAR(8) := &corid;
    v_avgmark NUMBER(2);
    v_maxmark NUMBER(2);
    v_minmark NUMBER(2);
    v_cordesc VARCHAR2(255);

    ex_CourseNotFound EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
    SELECT Count(M.stuid),
           M.corid,
           Avg(M.mark),
           Max(M.mark),
           Min(M.mark),
           C.descript
    INTO   v_marstuid, v_corid, v_avgmark, v_maxmark,
    v_minmark, v_cordesc
    FROM   marks M
           inner join courses C
                   ON M.corid = C.corid
    WHERE  C.corid = v_corid;

    dbms_output.Put_line (v_corid
                          || ' - '
                          || v_cordesc);

    dbms_output.Put_line ('Course Stats: ');

    dbms_output.Put_line ('Number of students: '
                          || v_marstuid);

    dbms_output.Put_line ('Average: '
                          || v_avgmark);

    dbms_output.Put_line ('Marks Range: ');

    dbms_output.Put_line ('High: '
                          || v_maxmark);

    dbms_output.Put_line ('Low: '
                          || v_minmark);

EXCEPTION
    WHEN ex_CourseNotFound THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_corcode || ' Does not exist.');
END;

/
```

[Table used]

[image: 1]

Comment: I don't know anything about Oracle syntax, but shouldn't strings be quoted? Like `v_corid CHAR(8) := 'ETHI1022';`?

Comment: @Arvo So that is the output it is giving me. The & is what tells it to prompt the user running the file to input something, so it is placing ETHI1022 there on it's own. You're right though it's treating the input like it's a variable but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ETHI1022 it should be 'ETHI1022'. Your inner join is fine. From where you are getting value of `corid`. Make it of type varchar/string or something like that.

Or you might try  `v_corid CHAR(8) :=  ''''||&corid||'''';`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm not sure how to make it treat the input as a string. When I run the code with that it gives me this:

ORA-01741: illegal zero-length identifier

That is from running it with double quotes, with single quotes it gives me the same error as before.

Comment: I did `'''||&corid||'''` and it works, but now for some reason it is telling me that the string buffer is too small for v_marstuid even if i have it set to take the datatype straight from the db. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: I think there's something wrong with my select statement but I'm not sure what. I am now able to get the bind variable to work but now I'm getting ORA-00937 Not a single group group function...